# Unit test for thrown exception

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a Spring Boot application where I have methods in my Service layer like:

```
    public List<PlacementDTO> getPlacementById(final int id) throws MctException {
    List<PlacementDTO> placementList;
    try {
        placementList = placementDao.getPlacementById(id);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new MctException("Error retrieving placement data", ex);
    }
    return placementList;
}
```

What is the best way to unit test that MctException will be thrown?  I tried:

```
    @Test(expected = MctException.class)
public void testGetPlacementByIdFail() throws MctException, SQLException {
    when(placementDao.getPlacementById(15)).thenThrow(MctException.class);
    placementService.getPlacementById(15);
}
```

However, this doesn't test the right that an exception is actually thrown.

Comment: "[...] this doesn't test the right that an exception is actually thrown." - What exactly do you mean? You use the correct way (via `@Test(...)` annotation) to test for exceptions and this annotation does check that the correct exception is thrown.

Comment: Should be `when(placementDao.getPlacementById(15)).thenThrow(SQLException.class);` The dao throws a SQLException, which is then wrapped by an MctException and thrown by the method.

Comment: Thank you Compass...that is the behavior I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to stub the `placementDao.getPlacementById(15)` call to throw the `SQLException` instead of your `MctException`, like this:

```
@Test(expected = MctException.class)
public void testGetPlacementByIdFail() throws MctException, SQLException {
    when(placementDao.getPlacementById(15)).thenThrow(SQLException.class);
    placementService.getPlacementById(15);
}
```

This way when you call your Service method `placementService.getPlacementById(15);` you know that your `MctException` will encapsulate the `SQLException` and therefore your test could expect the `MctException` exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thank you...that is the behavior I was looking for.  I thought I had tried that, but obviously not! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try out the [ExepctionException](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) rule feature of Junit. This would allow greater granularity in verification of your exception handling in your unit test than the expected exception annotation.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testGetPlacementByIdFail(){
  thrown.expect(MctException.class);
  thrown.expectMessage("Error retrieving placement data");
  //Test code that throws the exception
}
```

As the above snippet show, you would also be able to test on various properties of the exception like its message.